# Cloud Functions for Firebase with custom HTTP path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way of defining the HTTP path (after the first '/') to access a Cloud Function for Firebase?

What I'm tying to achieve is to create a rest-like path system to access the functions.

I have a [GitHub](https://github.com/bateramos/spotter_server) with my project if there is any doubts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `cloudfunctions.net` domain will route all traffic beginning with a function name to that function. So, for example, you could do this with a standard Express app:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/bar', (req, res) => {
  res.end('bar');
});

app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
  res.end('foo');
});

exports.myFunc = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The above will allow you to make requests to `/myFunc/foo` and `/myFunc/bar` and handle them separately. One thing to note is that currently if you pass an Express app there will be an error if you try to access your function at `/myFunc`, instead needing to make your request to `/myFunc/` (with a trailing slash).

Comment: '/myFunc' woks for me

Comment: is it possible to do this without express? Introducing express for simple functions would affect startup time (cold boot).

Comment: Sure, you can just `switch (req.path) { case "/foo": ... }`

Comment: How to do a dynamic path example `/myFunc/some_id`? Thanks a lot