# Is it possible to create a default function with Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When you create a function with Cloud Functions for Firebase you get a url something like this - https://firebase-app.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld - I want to be able to create a cname to go to a url like this - https://firebase-app.cloudfunctions.net/ - Is it possible to create a "default function" which would give me a root path like that?
 If not, will it be possible in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should try to [create your own Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195930/cloud-functions-for-firebase-with-custom-http-path) app and specify routes through that.

If that's not what you want, please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to indicate that you're interested in this.

You can also try to fully control you own domain powered by Cloud Functions by [using a reverse proxy](http://abe.ghost.io/using-a-custom-domain-with-google-cloud-functions-for-firebase/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I was mainly wanting it to do some server side rendering of some dynamic html pages. The reverse proxy is pretty close to what I am wanting, but would be easier if Firebase just had it built in. I went ahead and filed a feature request in Firebase. I would link it here, but not sure where the request is now.

Comment: Integration between static Firebase Hosting (where you can use your own domain name) and more dynamic stuff like Cloud Functions on node.js is actually a commonly requested feature.  I believe the team is looking into it.